# Use Floating Button in another xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, action

I create a Floating Button in xml then I put it in another xml using include,and now I'm trying to do action in this floating Button but the project stop when I run it .. so I want to now how can I do action in specific button from another xml

action_bar xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"

    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:src="@drawable/play_pause"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I include the floating Button inside another XML:

```
<include layout="@layout/control_bar">
</include>
```

java class

```
        playButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.play);

  }



    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to your include tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/control_bar"
android:id="@+id/example1">
</include>`
```

then use that id in your java code to make a listener:

```
playButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.example1);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
...
        }
```

Comment: Still not work , there is an error on the name of id example1 "cannot resolve symbol example1 "

Comment: I tested the answer and found no errors..
check:
1. that you have design lib in your dependencies
2.check your include tag is pointing to right layout // maybe there is some typos
3.be sure you have just one tag in your floating action button XML .
4.check for any typos at all.